# Creating a rectangle - Coordinates - Haskell

Tags: haskell, shapes

I'm trying to create a raster graphic. At the moment, I've created code for a rectangle, however, the code only works for a 3x3 rectangle. I'm not sure how to improve the code so it works for 4x4, 5x5 etc. Here is what I have:

```
rectangleRaster :: Coord -> Coord -> Raster
rectangleRaster (x1, y1) (x2, y2) = [((x1, y1), 1.0), ((x1, y1 + y2), 1.0)] ++ [((x1, y2), 1.0), ((x1 + x2, y1), 1.0)] ++ [((x2 + x1, y2), 1.0), ((x2, y1), 1.0)] ++ [((x2, y2 + y1), 1.0), ((x2, y2), 1.0)]
```

I see that the problem is everytime I want a bigger rectangle I need to add more points to `rectangleRaster`. So how could I use recursion or something else so when I input some points it creates a full rectangle without gaps. Here is what is prints for the points:

Points: (-1, -1) (1, 1)
[image: (-1, -1) (1, 1)]

Points: (-2, 1) (2, -1)
[image: (-2, 1) (2, -1)]

Comment: Can you explain, for example in pseudo-code how you would construct such a list?

Comment: Your function's return value is built from 4 segments that are `(++)` 'ed together - that makes sense. But each of those is only 2 points.  Make a function that takes 2 points, and returns a variable number of points that form a line between the two points. Look into list comprehensions and concepts related to those: step sizes, guards, generators, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rasterized rectangle can be expressed simply as:
 Every point `(x', y')` that exist between `(x1, y1)` and `(x2,y2)` that satisfy any number of the following conditions:
 - `x == x1`
 - `x == x2`
 - `y == y1`
 - `y == y2`
List comprehension is a decent start for what you want. As a hint, here's the list comprehension that would give you a filled square between `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)`:

```
pointList = [(x', y') | x' <- [x1..x2], y' <- [y1..y2]]
```

From there, work your way further by finding how to specify which of those points should make it into the list. You can read up on list comprehension, for example at:
 https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension.

Good luck!